# How to solve this PDE: $p\sqrt x+q\sqrt y =\sqrt z$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this PDE, using Lagrange's method: 
$p\sqrt x+q\sqrt y  =\sqrt z$

Lagrange's auxiliary equation is:
$\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\frac {dy}{\sqrt y}= \frac{dz}{\sqrt z}$

I already know the answer to this on which is $f(\sqrt x - \sqrt y, \sqrt y - \sqrt z)$ , but I don't know the complete solution and I have tried to solve it but I can't quite get to the same answer.

Comment: What is it PDE?

Comment: What you've posted does not contain any partial derivatives... Try reading the question again?

Comment: This is a partial differential equation of the form Pp+Qq=R, where P, Q and R are functions of x, y, z.

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Partial Differential Equation. This is a standard form of a linear partial differential equation of the first order ( Lagrange's linear equation ).

Comment: @BernardMassé p here is dz/dy and q is dz/dx

Comment: You should not write $\sqrt x p$.  Either $p\sqrt x$ or $\sqrt{xp}$.

Comment: @DanielV Thanks, I have edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\sqrt{y} \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =\sqrt z$$
Your general solution on the form of implicit equation : $\quad f(\sqrt x - \sqrt y, \sqrt y - \sqrt z)=0\quad$ is correct.

An equivalent explicit form is :
$$ \sqrt y - \sqrt z =\phi( \sqrt x - \sqrt y)$$
where $\phi$ is any differentiable function.

As a consequence :
$$z(x,y)=\bigg(\sqrt y - \phi( \sqrt x - \sqrt y)\bigg)^2$$

IN ADDITION :

System of characteristic ODEs : $\quad\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}=\frac{dz}{\sqrt z}$

First family of characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}\quad\to\quad \sqrt x-\sqrt y=c_1$

Second family of characteristic curves, from $\quad \frac{dz}{\sqrt z}=\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}\quad\to\quad \sqrt z-\sqrt y=c_2$

General solution : $\quad\sqrt y - \sqrt z =\phi( \sqrt x - \sqrt y)$

$$z(x,y)=\bigg(\sqrt y - \phi( \sqrt x - \sqrt y)\bigg)^2$$

Comment: I know that this is the answer, but I don't know how to get to it. I have tried couple of times, and I don't get this same answer.

Comment: See the addition to my main answer.